# How do I check the succesfull retry with separate command in ansible?

Tags: ansible

Ansible 2.9.6

There is standard way to use retry in Ansible.

```
- name: run my command
  register: result
  retries: 5
  delay: 60
  until: result.rc == 0
  shell:
    cmd: >
      mycommand.sh
```

`until` is a passive check here.
How can I do the check with the separate command? Like "retry `command A` several times until `command B` return 0"

Of cause I may put both commands inside shell execution "commandA ; commandB" and I will get exit status of the second one for the `result.rc`. But is any Ansible way to do this?

Comment: If you are running all this on localhost, you could try to use a pipe lookup for your commandB but that's quite ugly IMO. On a remote target I don't see at first glance any other way than putting all your checks in a single script. And that looks like the best solution anyway: check all your conditions inside your script, return the according code and retry until all is ok. Meanwhile, you might want to edit your question to give more background info about you actually do with your scripts as there might be a pure ansible way to achieve your goal that does not involve using shell.

Answer (score 0):

The *ansible way* would point towards retries over a `block` or `include` that contains a `command` task for each script. However, [that's not supported](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/46203). You can use a modified version of [the workaround described here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/46203#issuecomment-556013701), though, but it starts to get complicated. Therefore, you may prefer to take [Zeitounator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68482605/how-do-i-check-the-succesfull-retry-with-separate-command-in-ansible#comment121031043_68482605)'s suggestion.